# Buildkit won't install on Ubuntu

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

I'm trying to install the buildkit tools on a Ubuntu based virtual machine install of a LAMP pre-made vm.
I've tried as root (bad form) and I tried as www-data, which is the same user as apache and has sudo privileges.  I don't understand what is blocking me here -  why am I getting this error?

```
> npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop
> working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent
> this by migrating to Yarn:
> https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/ npm WARN
> engine protractor@4.0.14: wanted: {"node":">=4.2.x"} (current:
> {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN deprecated
> graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility
> with current and future versions of Node.js npm WARN deprecated
> minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid
> a RegExp DoS issue npm WARN deprecated connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x
> series is deprecated npm WARN engine node-version@1.1.0: wanted:
> {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm
> WARN engine mime@1.6.0: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current:
> {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN optional dep failed,
> continuing fsevents@1.1.3 npm WARN engine request@2.83.0: wanted:
> {"node":">= 4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm ERR!
> 404 Not Found npm ERR! 404  npm ERR! 404 'types/selenium-webdriver' is
> not in the npm registry. npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to
> publish it npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of
> 'protractor' npm ERR! 404  npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install
> from a npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
> 
> npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-5-amd64 npm ERR! command
> "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" npm ERR! cwd
> /var/www/buildkit npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29 npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21 npm
> ERR! code E404 npm WARN engine har-validator@5.0.3: wanted:
> {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN
> engine hawk@6.0.2: wanted: {"node":">=4.5.0"} (current:
> {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine form-data@2.3.2:
> wanted: {"node":">= 0.12"} (current:
> {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine har-schema@2.0.0:
> wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})
> npm WARN engine sntp@2.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current:
> {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine hoek@4.2.1: wanted:
> {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm
> WARN engine cryptiles@3.1.2: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current:
> {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine boom@4.3.1: wanted:
> {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm
> WARN engine boom@5.2.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current:
> {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine co@4.6.0: wanted:
> {"iojs":">= 1.0.0","node":">= 0.12.0"} (current:
> {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})
> 
> > phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install /var/www/buildkit/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
> > node install.js
> 
> 
> /var/www/buildkit/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/boom/lib/index.js:5
> const Hoek = require('hoek'); ^^^^^ SyntaxError: Use of const in
> strict mode.
>     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>     at require (module.js:380:17)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/buildkit/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/lib/index.js:5:33)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32) npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node" npm WARN For further
> explanations, please read /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian   npm
> ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat
> '/var/www/buildkit/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/lodash/unionBy.js'
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log, npm ERR!
> including the npm and node versions, at: npm ERR!    
> <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
> 
> npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-5-amd64 npm ERR! command
> "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" npm ERR! cwd
> /var/www/buildkit npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29 npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21 npm
> ERR! path
> /var/www/buildkit/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/lodash/unionBy.js
> npm ERR! fstream_path
> /var/www/buildkit/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/lodash/unionBy.js
> npm ERR! fstream_type File npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter npm ERR!
> code ENOENT npm ERR! errno 34 npm ERR! fstream_stack
> /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26 npm ERR! fstream_stack
> Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:107:15)
> 
> > ws@0.4.32 install /var/www/buildkit/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
> 
> make: Entering directory
> '/var/www/buildkit/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
> CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o  
> SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node  
> SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished  
> COPY Release/bufferutil.node   CXX(target)
> Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o   SOLINK_MODULE(target)
> Release/obj.target/validation.node   SOLINK_MODULE(target)
> Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished   COPY
> Release/validation.node make: Leaving directory
> '/var/www/buildkit/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
> npm ERR!  npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in: npm
> ERR!     /var/www/buildkit/npm-debug.log npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue was resolved by installing nodejs from nodejs.org.  The Ubuntu version doesn't working with the buildkit.